# Extract Word Templates from String

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string

Is there a quick way to extract the argument-value pairs from below string in Python?

```
s = '[ARG0: elephants] were [ARGM-TMP: first] [V: walk] [ARGM-DIR: up]'
```

Output is in the form below:

```
ARG0 = elephants
ARGM-TMP = first
ARGM-DIR = up
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find all `arg`/`value` pairs using `re.findall` and build a dictionary by splitting the strings:

```
import re
s = '[ARG0: elephants] were [ARGM-TMP: first] [V: walk] [ARGM-DIR: up]'

d = re.findall(r'\[(ARG.*?\:*?)]', s)

dict([i.split(': ') for i in d])
# {'ARG0': 'elephants', 'ARGM-TMP': 'first', 'ARGM-DIR': 'up'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) in python. And you can use a regex string like the following.

```
\[(?P<key>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+): (?P<value>[a-z]+)\]
```